# Angular HttpClient unit tests won't fail when comparing data inside of an asynchronous function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to unit test a few simple GET requests and no matter what I do, I can't get the tests to fail.

If I change the `('GET')` to `('POST')` it will fail, but all of the api data passes no matter what.

```js
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { mockPhoneNumbers } from '../mocks/data/phoneNumbers.mock';
import { PhoneNumberApiService } from './phone-number-api.service';

describe('PhoneNumberApiService', () => {
  let service: PhoneNumberApiService;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [PhoneNumberApiService],
    });

    service = TestBed.get(PhoneNumberApiService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // After every test, assert that there are no more pending requests.
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should get the phone numbers successfully', () => {
    service
      .getPhoneNumbers()
      .subscribe(phoneNumbers => {
        expect(phoneNumbers).toEqual('bob');
        expect(phoneNumbers[0].id).toEqual('b8bfea4d-a26f-9e4e-cbd4-39eb69cdaa58');
        expect(phoneNumbers[1].friendlyName).toEqual('Dev Test');
      });

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('phoneNumbers');

    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

    req.flush(mockPhoneNumbers);
  });

  it('should get the phone number details successfully', () => {
    const { id: phoneNumberId } = mockPhoneNumbers[0];

    service
      .getPhoneNumberDetails(phoneNumberId)
      .subscribe(phoneNumber => expect(phoneNumber).toEqual(mockPhoneNumbers[0]));

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(`phoneNumbers/${phoneNumberId}`);

    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

    req.flush('bob');
  });
});
```

Surely flushing the request with the mock data and then expecting the mock data to be `bob` is wrong. In the bottom test, flushing the request with `bob` and expecting the data to be equal to the first phone number in the array should fail.

Comment: The assertion in the subscription only happens *after* the test has passed. Read up on the DoneFn, it's covered in https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: This is example is basically the same as the one used in the Angular docs for testing HttpClient. Did they forget to include something?

Comment: Okay, so adding done seems to cause the tests to fail. I wonder if this has something to do with using jest vs karma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem about your tests is that you make your "it" functions and expects asynchronous without explicit telling jasmine that .

You need to use the done function in other to tell for the test waiting for something (check out in [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/) a good tutorial about async test on jasmine)

Follows an example based on your code:

```
...
//Receive the done function like this
it('should get the phone numbers successfully', (done) => {
    service
      .getPhoneNumbers()
      .subscribe(phoneNumbers => {
        expect(phoneNumbers).toEqual('bob');
        expect(phoneNumbers[0].id).toEqual('b8bfea4d-a26f-9e4e-cbd4-39eb69cdaa58');
        expect(phoneNumbers[1].friendlyName).toEqual('Dev Test');
        //Tell the test that only in here all the work was done
        done();
      });
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('phoneNumbers');

    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

    req.flush(mockPhoneNumbers);
});
....
```

Also, to answer [your guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54295582/angular-httpclient-unit-tests-wont-fail-when-comparing-data/54295779#comment95411640_54295582), jest is a test runner and is build on top of jasmine framework (meaning the jest syntax is similar to jasmin, but not equal). But for this case I guess that usage of the done will solve your problem.